# How to use cv haarclassifier cascade

Tags: opencv

what does cascade->flag and cascade->count signify 
I want to use this trained haar classifier to detect face , how can I use without using opencv ready made function .

Answer (score 0):

Here is my function applying `cvHaarDetectObjects` using cascade from opencv. I use `cv::resize` to perform detection on small image (faster) and `cv::equalizeHist`.
`Flags` is the signature and `count` is the number of stages in the cascade.
You should read the opencv [documentation](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/c/objdetect_cascade_classification.html).

```
cv::Rect Detect(const cv::Mat & img){
  assert(img.type()==CV_8U);
  // rectangle result
  cv::Rect rdet;
  // small img size
  int w = img.cols/img_scale_;
  int h = img.rows/img_scale_;
  if((small_img_.rows!=h) || (small_img_.cols!=w))small_img_.create(h,w,CV_8U);
  // grayscale img
  cv::Mat gray;
  if(img.channels() == 1)gray = img;
  else{
    gray=cv::Mat(img.rows,img.cols,CV_8U);
    cv::cvtColor(img,gray,CV_BGR2GRAY);
  }
  cv::resize(gray,small_img_,cv::Size(w,h),0,0,CV_INTER_LINEAR);
  cv::equalizeHist(small_img_,small_img_);
  // perform detection
  cvClearMemStorage(storage_);
  IplImage ipl_simg = small_img_;
  CvSeq* obj = cvHaarDetectObjects(&ipl_simg,cascade_,storage_,
                                scale_factor_,min_neighbors_,0,min_size_);
  if(obj->total == 0){
    return cv::Rect(0,0,0,0);
  }
  int maxv = 0;
  for(int i = 0; i < obj->total; i++){
    CvRect* r = (CvRect*)cvGetSeqElem(obj,i);
      if(i == 0 || maxv < r->width*r->height){
        maxv = r->width*r->height;
        rdet.x = r->x*img_scale_;
        rdet.y = r->y*img_scale_;
        rdet.width  = r->width*img_scale_;
        rdet.height = r->height*img_scale_;
      }  
    }
  cvRelease((void**)(&obj));
  return rdet;
}
```

Comment: Here u are using opencv . I want to detect without it . Just don't know how to use the cascade classifier .